# Is the path that a planet takes orbiting the sun a centripetal one or one that follows a geodesic path?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, geodesics, tidal-effect

Is the path that a planet takes orbiting the sun a centripetal one or one that follows a geodesic path? My point is that if the planet follows a centripetal path all objects on the planet will experience a varying force depending on whether they are on the inner side of the planet as it is orbiting or the outer side. If as Einstein states the planet is following a curved / space time geodesic then there will be no forces acting on the planet or objects on the surface of that planet. It appears to me that it cannot be both and that a simple experiment will prove one or the other true.

Answer (score 2):

A planet orbiting a central body is subject to gravitation as a force in Newtonian mechanics. Only one point on the planet accelerates toward the central body as would be suggested by Newton's law of gravitation. The planet forces particles at points removed from this key point to accelerate in a way that differs from the gravitational acceleration toward the central body at the point. From the perspective of Newtonian mechanics, tides result from the gradient of the gravitational acceleration vector, mathematically described by the Newtonian tidal tensor).

A planet is subject to gravitation as the curvature of space-time caused by the central body in the context of general relativity. Only one point on the planet follows a geodesic about this central body. The planet forces particles at points removed from this key point follow a curve that is not a geodesic.  From the perspective of general relativity, tides result from the geodesic deviation, mathematically described by the Riemann curvature tensor.

Just as geodesics in general relativity becomes Newtonian orbits in the limit of velocities that are very small compared to the speed of light and distances that are very large compared to the Schwarzschild radius, the Riemann curvature tensor becomes the Newtonian tidal tensor in this limit.

Answer (score 1):

From the simple perspective of looking at the differential in the force, this is something we most certainly do observe. This is called tidal forcing and is what makes planets elongated in the direction along the radial path to the star, causes tides in the oceans and, in the extremes, leads to tidal breakup and tidal disruption events. The idea behind all of these is that the gravitational force is greater at the side of the planet closer to the sun (or other body such as moon, black hole etc.) then the side that is farther. Since the force scales as the inverse square, for large objects or close objects, the difference can be very large, even enough to rip the object apart.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If this is the case then my point would be that would a body such as the Earth travelling through curved space time and along it’s geodesic path experience such an effect. Surely the earth should be experiencing ‘free fall’ in the well of the suns gravity and as such not be subject to any centripetal forces at all ? Sorry if this sounds naive but I just cannot get my head around this !

Answer (score 0):

A body in free fall describes a geodesic per definition. A planet orbits a central mass in free fall and thus follows a geodesic. Strictly however this is true only for its center of mass, because all other points feel forces as you say and thus are not in free fall.